# Excel VBA Command Button shows error for UserForm.Show

Tags: excel, vba, userform

This is the first time I'm asking a question on Stack Overflow so please forgive me if I'm not completely 100% clear in what my problem is.

**A bit of context:** I'm working on an automated Accounting system and I'm trying to add a UserForm to add new transactions to the General Ledger. I already achieved a Macro in Excel that generates Invoice in PDF Format and adds the data to the general ledger. Now I want to partly automise the process for incoming invoices by means of the UserForm.

The UserForm itself looks pretty need if I might say so myself. I'll try to [add a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3adq.png) to give an idea of what it looks like and what I get for input. I finished the entire coding of the UserForm, including the command for the command button, the UserForm_Initialize, and all the extra button coding needed to make it work.. So I thought. When I execute the code, it gives me several errors (amongst others, error 361 "Can't load or unload file"). The debug process shows that the error occurs in the "UserForm.Show" line of the command button.

The code that I have until now is as follows:

**CommandButton**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Load UserFormTransactions
UserFormTransactions.Show
End Sub
```

**UserForm Initialize:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Clearing Input boxes
Input_Type.Clear
Reference.Value = ""
Invoice_Date.Value = ""
PaymentTerm.Value = ""
VAT_Percent.Clear
Amount.Value = ""
Comment.Value = ""
Transaction_Type.Clear
Quarter1.Value = True

'Populate ComboBox - Input_Type
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Types")
For Each rng In ws.Range("Type")
    
    Me.Input_Type.AddItem rng
Next rng

'Populate ComboBox - VAT_Percent
Set ws = Worksheets("Types")
For Each rng In ws.Range("VAT_per_cent")

    Me.VAT_Percent.AddItem rng
Next rng

'Populate ComboBox - Transaction_Type
Set ws = Worksheets("Types")
For Each rng In ws.Range("List_Transaction_Types")

    Me.Transaction_Type.AddItem rng
Next rng

'Set Focus on Input_Type Box
Input_Type.SetFocus

End Sub
```

**Add Transaction Button:**

```
Private Sub Add_Click()
Dim LR As Long
Dim NR As Long

SheetName1 = "Transactions"

Worksheets(SheetName1).Activate

LR = Range("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
NR = Cells(LR, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Transfer Information
Cells(NR, 4).Value = Input_Type.Value
Cells(NR, 5).Value = Invoice_Date.Value
Cells(NR, 6).Value = PaymentTerm.Value
Cells(NR, 7).Value = Reference.Value
Cells(NR, 8).Value = Amount.Value
Cells(NR, 9).Value = VAT_Percent.Value
Cells(NR, 10).Value = Transaction_Type.Value
Cells(NR, 19).Value = Comment.Value

If Quarter1.Value = True Then Cells(NR, 3).Value = Quarter1.Caption
If Quarter2.Value = True Then Cells(NR, 3).Value = Quarter2.Caption
If Quarter3.Value = True Then Cells(NR, 3).Value = Quarter3.Caption
If Quarter4.Value = True Then Cells(NR, 3).Value = Quarter4.Caption

End Sub
```

Besides I have the coding for the Cancel and Clear button, but those are trivial and I expect there is no error in those. Anyone who could help me with this problem? All help is most appreciated.

Thanks,

Maarten

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line of `UserForm_Initialize` (`F9`) and step thru it (`F8`) - How far does it get?

Comment: In the VB editor go to *Tools > Options > General > Error Trapping* and make sure you've set that to "Break in class module".  Otherwise you won't be able to debug errors occurring in your userform.